# How to create two conditions to change the icon when the state changes and the condition downloaded from the API

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

In the React Native application, I display the downloaded clubs from the API as a JSON object in the object there is a value whether the club is in the favorites:

```json
Object {
  "address": "ul. Przy lesie",
  "bookmark": false,
  "name": "Akademia Tenisa Paliński",
  "status": 1,
}
```

Using FlatList it displays all clubs and next to the club I create a heart icon if the club is in favorites using JSON object "bookmark": true if true the heart is to be filled, and if false is to be empty.Performs a check whit a code:

```js
        <View style={styles.club__favorite}>
          {/* condition if club included in favorite screen */}
          {item.bookmark ? (
            <AntDesign name="heart" size={30} color="#40514e" />
          ) : (
            <AntDesign name="hearto" size={30} color="#40514e" />
          )}
        </View>
```

AntDesign are @expo/vector-icons imported icons. My problem comes here. Now I would like the user to be able to click on an empty heart that is not in the favorites so that it changes to a full heart. I tried to solve the type of checking if the same element exists in the array, if so, it should change the icon:

```js
        <View style={styles.club__favorite}>
          {/* condition if club included in favorite screen */}
          {item.bookmark ? (
            <AntDesign name="heart" size={30} color="#40514e" />
          ) : (
            <AntDesign name="hearto" size={30} color="#40514e" />
          )}
          {favoriteClub.includes(item) ? (
            <AntDesign name="heart" size={30} color="#40514e" />
          ) : (
            <AntDesign name="hearto" size={30} color="#40514e" />
          )}
        </View>
```

This condition works, but I have double hearts and the application must check with the API whether the club is in the favorites and click on the icons to change their status. I don't know how to create two conditions for one icon to light.

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: I am assuming you already have new updated heart data (i think favoriteClub is doing same)You can do same this using :
``
    {item.bookmark || favoriteClub.includes(item) ? (
                <AntDesign name="heart" size={30} color="#40514e" />
              ) : (
                <AntDesign name="hearto" size={30} color="#40514e" />
              )}

``
Better way would be HeartClick update api response and fetch or return response from api latest one. It will automatically re-render your component. In that way you don't need to track for favoriteClub

Comment: Thank you so much. It's working how should it.